Why didn’t these jump leads work, how to ensure I get correct leads?

I bought these jump leads a while ago and they seem to be pretty useless or not very good.  I lost the packaging so do not know the brand or specification.
Due to non use my battery had depleted to below 3 volts possibly even below 1 volt(can’t remember the exact reading).  I then used these jump leads but car wasn’t starting.
We then borrowed a pair of jump leads which felt far more heavier and quality and they started the car right up.

So is there a way to know for sure which jump leads will work for a car(I’m my case civic coupe vti 1999)?

I’ve just been looking at jump leads on argos website and again not sure how to discern if something is good enough.  One AA branded productfor £18 says it’s suitable for petrol engines up to 3litres and is 3 meters long but doesn’t say anything else.  Another RAC branded lead on argos is selling for £37 and also mentions its 25mm squared.  I’d rather buy the £18 item as it’s cheerful and cheap but if it’s useless like my curren one there would be no point.  How can I know if the cheaper or even the more expensive one would be sufficient?


Thanks

In America, wire gauge size determines current carrying capability. 8 ga, is minimum, 4 ga. better, 2 ga best. The smaller the number, the greater the amount of copper wires to carry 50-250+ amps of near instant boost starting.  And be wary of copper plated aluminum jumper cables as they're cheap and not better than 100% copper wires.

There are two possible ways to use jumper cables, as we call them in the colonies. You can connect any cheap jumper cables from the jumping car to the jumped car, and then run the jumping car at fast idle for a prolonged time such as fifteen to thirty minutes before you attempt to start the car. The jumping car is serving as a big expensive battery charger. As long as the dead battery in the jumped car is still capable of taking a charge, this works no matter how poor the quality of the jumper cables, because you are only asking them to pass a charging current of perhaps 20-50 amps, not a starting current of hundreds of amps.
If you wish to connect jumper cables and immediately start a car that has a totally dead battery, you need jumper cables with very heavy wire and very strong clamps. Look at the wire from which the factory supplied battery cables are made on the jumped car. Not the insulation thickness but the actual metallic core of the cable. That's how thick your jumper cables' wire should be, or close to it, for instant starting.
If you can't find jumper cables with conductors that thick, buy the thickest ones you can find and leave the vehicles connected for at least a few minutes before attempting to start.
Unsatisfied with the quality of available jumper cables, I made my own many years ago from AWG 4/0 ultraflexible welding cable and 400 amp clamps that take a two-handed squeeze to open. They will start any vehicle on the road instantly without even running the engine on the jumping vehicle because the cables and clamps are capable of passing so many amps.
